# Mesh lags while following the armature. How to fix it?

Tags: mesh, armature, bones, drivers

I've made a simple rig for my jaw model. While testing it I discovered that tongue IK spline bones don't follow the jaw bone correct (there is a lag there). Has anyone had the similar problem? Thanks in advance for any tips how to fix it.
[image]

Comment: Are you using drivers?

Comment: Yes I do. The deformation JAW bone has 3 drivers applied. It is controlled by by the JAW controller bone (with a custom shape as pictured above).

Comment: I think its drivers delay in the vewport when you manually move the bones, I had some kind of similar problem, check if it works ok with keyframes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try to get rid of drivers and test it once more.

Comment: try to keyframe the CTRL jaw, I dont think you need to remove drivers

Comment: also check this https://themendingpath.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/axis-c2-jaw.png

Comment: Deleting drivers didn't help at all. You're right, this blocky movement isn't visible after keyfaming, but somehow it irritates me :). Oh, and thanks for the anathomic tip.

Comment: What happens, when you move the jaw and release the operation by right-clicking (cancel)? Do all bones go back to their respective rest position? If not, you almost certainly have a cyclic dependency in your setup somewhere. These do cause lagging as seen here. However, I do not want to rule out the possibility of drivers interfering.

Comment: @Anudiz You may be right saying that this is bones dependency problem (cause it has nothing to do with drivers). I've read one thread about it somewhere lately. I'll try to test different combinations and post an answer if find a solution.