# Rigging a face lagging on animation

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, constraints

I'm learning to create my own rig. When rigging a face using multiple constraints (stretch to & copy location) the control points of my rig update slowly when moved. Like if I rotate the head at the base or the neck quickly, the cheeks and chin etc. are left behind and slowly catch up. (Especially when the preview animation ends and jumps back to frame 1)

Is there a method of rigging I should know about? perhaps the order of the constraints? Or should I not even be using specific constraints to for the face? Or perhaps this is only in the preview and not in the render.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48978/mesh-lags-while-following-the-armature-how-to-fix-it

Comment: I discovered a few issues. having doubled up location restraints, constraint stacking order, and 2 bones with crossed copy location restraints. Having 2 bones effect each other is the lead issue I was having next to stacking order. Thanks for the link- Paul Gonet